# What macro means in LaTeX?

Tags: macros

Many of the latex packages used the term macro what does it mean and what is the definition of macro according to LaTeX and what is the use of this macro? Kindly let me know with examples. Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Macro processing is a particular idiom  for programming languages see for example [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General-purpose_macro_processor).

Apart from TeX, other well known macro systems include `m4`, The C pre-processor, and the SGML/XML/HTML entity mechanism.

Almost all commands that you can define in latex are macros, which are replaced by their definitions of lower-level commands as the macro is "expanded".

In a macro processor (unlike a compiled language) the main mechanism is textual replacement  so after

```
\newcommand\foo{hello}
```

the input

```
\foo\space world
```

the macro `\foo` is not a pointer to some pre-compiled function, it points to its replacement text and is replaced in line so the processor then sees

```
hello\space world
```

just as if that had been the original input, and processing restarts with this as input. (Some details have been omitted in this description)

`\space` is a macro defined already in LaTeX, expanding to a space so the input finally becomes

```
hello world
```

which is a sequence of non expandable tokens which gets passed to TeX's typesetting core.

Comment: Is there any command that are not macros in LaTeX? @David Carlisle

Comment: yes all the TeX primitives for example. macros have to expand to something, so there has, in the end, to be something that they expand to.

Comment: Can we say anything which can replace as macros? @David Carlisle

Comment: Just you have mentioned in above "main mechanism is textual replacement so after" @David Carlisle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59052/discussion-between-biki-teron-and-david-carlisle).

Answer (score 3):

Macros in (La)TeX should be considered a *noun*. Then, according to [Merriam-Webster](//www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/macro):

> Definition of `macro`
>   *plural* `macros`
>   :  a single computer instruction that stands for a sequence of operations

All other things coded at the package and class level rely on macros and some deeper *primitives* - part of the TeX core.