Understanding TeX terminology
I'm new to TeX and want to make sure I understand some of the terminology. If I understand correctly,
you have a .tex file, which is just plain text, like .txt. The extension .tex signifies that the text contains commands or macros (not sure what exactly macros are or if they're the same as commands, like \maketitle) that are compiled (made into a typeset document) by a TeX engine, which is just a computer program. Examples of TeX engines are the original TeX, XeTeX, and pdfTeX (which also includes LaTeX).
A TeX distribution or distro contains a TeX frontend or editor (which is like normal text editing software but tailored to suit TeX commands), the various engines (programs that compile the .txt or .tex) themselves, as well as packages which give the engines extra functionality. In the editor, you can choose what engine you want to compile the text as each engine has different commands and such and produces a different output.
Can someone fact-check me on this please? I also didn't know what to tag this question, sorry about that.
Thank you.

close enough, not all distributions include an editor, texlive for example does not except on windows.  There are answers on site for the other bits but as I say your general description is more or less accurate.

Welcome! This is almost right. pdfTeX doesn't include LaTeX. LaTeX is a format. You can combine that format with any of the engines. So, you can use XeLaTeX, for example (XeTeX + LaTeX) or LuaLaTeX (LuaTeX + LaTeX) or original-ish TeX (original-ish-TeX + LaTeX). There are other formats, such as plain which can similarly be combined with different engines. Different formats have different commands etc. Different engines can, too, A TeX distro may include a front end, but often doesn't. Macros are one kind of command, but don't worry much about that to start.

for example many people use "command" and "macro" interchangably but "macro" has a specific definition independent of tex see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/468508/what-is-the-difference-between-macro-and-command/468541#468541

probably a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21863/tex-distribution-and-engine

So you might want to use LaTeX, but decide to use LuaLaTeX, for example, rather than pdfLaTeX.

@cfr Thank you. Can you please elaborate on what exactly a format is and how it's different from a TeX engine? Is it these formats or the engines that read the commands in the text file (or do the formats do the "reading" (interpreting commands) and the engines do the typesetting, with different engines producing different documents visually but with the same content when used with the same format)? Also, on MiKTeX's frontend, TeXWorks, when I go to compile the document, is what I'm choosing from the dropdown list a combination of an engine and a format?

Roughly: A format is a collection of definitions defined in terms of the basic features of core TeX. A format usually provides a higher-level interface. So you wouldn't want to have to tell TeX exactly what to do every time you want to emphasise a bit of text say: select this font and do apply it and make such-and-such correction etc. So a format might give you a command \emph{<text>} so you can just write \emph{something} when you want to emphasise something. So Knuth used plain to typeset The TeX Book. LaTeX is another format. I don't know TeXWorks but it is probably a combination.

In many cases, different engines produce visually similar output, but they may produce it in different ways. For example, one engine might produce DVI which you can post-process to produce postscript or PDF. Another, such as pdfTeX, might produce PDF directly. It is actually a little more complicated these days because when you can TeX, often you're calling pdfTeX in DVI mode .... But I would avoid worrying about this for now unless you're writing a dissertation on TeX (rather than in it). You probably want to use pdfLaTeX or LuaLaTeX to start.

Start with pdfLaTeX if you are in a discipline where journals require .tex submissions. Otherwise, luaLaTeX is probably a better choice to start.

@cfr So engines are programs which format text containing TeX commands and formats are extensions built on top of engines that simplify writing commands by letting only one command have the engine do multiple, yes? In the frontend, even though you have things like XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX, I can also select engines alone, like XeTeX and LuaTeX; when I choose to compile with only an engine, is the format used "plain", meaning that the engine has no extra functionality that simplifies writing commands? Thanks again.

@cloud No plain is itself a format. And formats are somewhat independent of engines. So LaTeX, for example, doesn't depend on a particular engine. You can use LaTeX with any of the major engines. Similarly for plain. Many documents will compile with any of these major engines with minor, if any, changes. And they will produce very similar output. There are fancy things you can do which mean that's not true. But, if you are just beginning, it's close enough to being true. But the differences make it easier to do some things with some engines. E.g. it's easier to typeset Japanese w/ LuaTeX.

Let me try to sort your keywords a little bit more.
TeX
This is how all things started. Donald Knuth, Mathematician and later Prof. for Informatics, was unhappy with the printed quality of books, especially when it came to mathematics. So he started to develop a typesetting program, which he called TeX. Started in 1978, frozen release version3.14 ... about a decade later. See more on Wikipedia.
A typical TeX content looks like this, if I recall correctly:
{\bf Hello} world
\bye

You compile it, at least in the 1980s, and still often today, from the command line like:
> tex yourFile
> pdftex yourFile

where the first one puts you on the dvi-route, and the second turns your file into a pdf.
It became a kind of standard to call your source files .tex, and the whole processing chain relies on this (to some extent).
Yes, it's plain ASCII, and as long as you stick to the TeX-syntax any ASCII-editor will be good enough. However, and Integrated Development Environment (IDE) is provided by many more dedicated editors.
For TeX-syntax see e.g. here.
What's special about TeX?
It is all about typesetting. Think of the time of Gutenberg, or the Chinese even earlier, put your lead-letters together to lines, blocks etc. Adjust spaces. Build paragraphs from lines, paragraphs from pages, documents from pages.
That's what TeX does.
And no, its outcome is not like you know from Word or other programs: It's hard to top Donalds patience, sense of beauty, and mathematical exactness for all those tiny little optimizing steps he built-in.
LaTeX
Now, though with TeX you could:

just write your text
and insert typesetting commands later or while you go

the final source file isn't always easy to digest for a human being. TeX compiler, better TeX' rules sometimes lead to unexpected results.
Moreover, if I get it right, at the time of development it was done in Pascal. In consequence a number of things weren't so nice on a practical base, like changed \defs (e.g. by including a package), tedious long lines just to typeset a little thing and so on.
That's when Leslie Lamport entered the scene and started a development, which resulted in LaTeX commands, built on TeX, in a more robust way. (This development isn't over yet, as L3 tries to and already exceeds LaTeX.)
Now users could focus on what they want to put, like a \section, a \table etc. and no longer had to fiddle with spacings and what have you.
Typical code would look line e.g.
\documentclass{article}

\begin[document}
 hello world!
\end{document}

As with TeX you could compile it to pdf from the command line like
> pdflatex yourFile

xyz-TeX
As you mentioned over time many dialects developed, based on different needs.
E.g. if you need to work with Unicode, like using Chinese or Japanese, though it's possible with LaTeX, using dedicated XeLaTeX is less painful, at least on the source code level.
You can find all those tex.exe, pdf.exe, pdflatex.exe etc. in the appropriate folder of your TeX-installation.
Distributions
As was already said, they come in all shapes and flavors, for almost all operating systems you can think of. Some may include IDEs, others don't.
E.g. I use MikTex (the tex-system) and TexMaker (IDE) on both Windows and Linux. This IDE lets you configure running a number of compiles, e.g. Latex, Xelatex, LuaTex etc.

LaTeX used \documentstyle etc. to begin with. Or maybe not even to begin with. \documentclass is 2e. I don't even know what 1 looked like. I've never seen any reference to it: it's always 2.09 or 2e or, now, 3.
